# Route 53 domains are unreachable after redeploying eks cluster setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dns, devops, amazon-route53

My domains wont open and it says theyre unreachable.I have deployed my frontend and backend application using k8s and routed the nginx ingress to route 53. I have provided all necessary IAM roles and permission to get into route 53. All ssl certs have been generated and are in TRUE/READY condition and all pods are working fine. I have provided sg with port 443 and port 80 open. The domains are already registered since the domain were working fine initially but due to some other problem we had to delete the cluster and redeploy the whole setup. Although checking the load balancer, port 443 isnt connected to any ssl cert(when checking from aws). ive used eksctl for the setup. when running nslookup it returns k8s' ingress endpoint in cname.

I tried modifying my ingress to allow the dnsZones manually.
I want the domains to be reachable and connected to the appropriate SSL certificate. I am also unsure from where do i look up the problem and what the problem exactly might be.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8deN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your selection of protocol TCP is incorrect. I can see that from your screenshot and also the security policy is showing 'not applicable' for the same reason. Please use TLS(Protocol TLS and Port 443) and then you will be able to set the following for the Load Balancer listener

1. Security policy Default
2. Default SSL/TLS certificate

Also always check the status of the target group if all the targets in the target group are healthy which is based on the health check it performs to see if your backend services are reachable.